# How should i implement human thinking logic in grammar AI?

Tags: python, logic, artificial-intelligence, grammar

As you may see in the title, I am looking for an useful way to implement human thinking logic into a grammar AI program. This would mean that the program should be able to recognize that the sentence "Cats eat mice" is logic and that the sentence "Mice eat cats" isn't.
The question is - Where should I start?
Is there any in-build or online program with same logic as I request?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well obviously the starting point is to come with a complete and unambiguous definition of what is a "logical" sentence and what is not one... Good luck.

Comment: The problem of extracting meaning from sentences is one that Google Translate and others have poured millions of man-hours and dollars into without getting a perfect solution yet. I would be surprised (to say the least) if someone has written a library that solves it.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to model [common sense reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonsense_reasoning). Maybe this term will help you find some suitable sources.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, "mice eat cats" is not illogical (and is of course not ungrammatical). It's just surprising.

So If I understand correctly, you're looking to evaluate the likelihood that the statement 'mice eat cats' is true.

One approach to this kind of common sense reasoning problem is to have lots of premises which set out the usual state of affairs.

Cats are usually bigger than mice. 
The eater is usually bigger than eaten.

You can then use this as a syllogism to build a further premise:

Therefore it is unusual for mice to eat cats.

You then need to hold known exceptions
The eater may be smaller than eaten where the eaten is dead.
The eater may be smaller than eaten where there are more eaters than eaten.
The eater may be smaller than eaten where it is eating a part of the eaten.

Then from the premise "mice eat cats" you can get to "it is unsual for mice to eat cats" and "Perhaps the cat is dead. Perhaps there are many mice. Perhaps the mice eat only a part of the cat. Perhaps the premise 'mice eat cats' is in error".

An interesting common sense reasoning application is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Mind_Common_Sense ... there's a practical reasoning api available described here

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.557&rep=rep1&type=pdf

However, bear in mind that it's... not very good yet. But it's a great starting point for augmented intelligence, for example - AI suggests, human confirms (which adds in a training element for the AI at the same time). You would then need to add lots of domain-specific concepts for the area you are interested in. This can be hard. I've been working on it for ten years!

https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/mintz.pdf may also be a good start point for building out your set of concepts. Try https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE for extracting concepts from corpuses.

Good luck with your endeavour.